# getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I keep getting "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException" when running the add method.

```
public class SortedListOfImmutables {

private Listable[] items;

/**
 * This constructor creates an empty list by creating an internal array
 * of size 0.  (Note that this is NOT the same thing as setting the internal
 * instance variable to null.) 
 */
public SortedListOfImmutables() {
    items = new Listable[0];
}

/**
 *  Copy constructor.  The current object will become a copy of the
 *  list that the parameter refers to.  
 *  
 *  The copy must be made in such a way that future changes to
 *  either of these two lists will not affect the other. In other words, 
 *  after this constructor runs, adding or removing things from one of 
 *  the lists must not have any effect on the other list.
 *  
 *  @param other the list that is to be copied
 */
public SortedListOfImmutables(SortedListOfImmutables other) {
    if(other != null) {
        items = new Listable[other.items.length];

        for(int index=0;index<other.items.length;index++){
            items[index] = other.items[index];
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Adds an item to the list.  This method assumes that the list is already
 * sorted in alphabetical order based on the names of the items in the list.
 * 
 * The new item will be inserted into the list in the appropriate place so
 * that the list will remain alphabetized by names.
 * 
 * In order to accommodate the new item, the internal array must be re-sized 
 * so that it is one unit larger than it was before the call to this method.
 *  
 * @param itemToAdd refers to a Listable item to be added to this list
 */
public void add(Listable itemToAdd) {
    if(itemToAdd != null) {
        SortedListOfImmutables temp = new SortedListOfImmutables();
        temp.items = new Listable[this.items.length+1];
        boolean added = false;

        if(this.items.length == 0)
            temp.items[0] = itemToAdd;

        else {
            for(int index = 0;index < this.items.length;index++) {
                if(this.items[index].getName().compareTo(itemToAdd.getName())>0)
                    temp.items[index] = items[index];
                else {
                    if(!added) {
                        temp.items[index] = itemToAdd;
                        added = true;
                    }
                    else temp.items[index+1] = this.items[index];
                }
            }
        }
        this.items = new Listable[temp.items.length];

        for(int tempIndex = 0;tempIndex < temp.items.length;tempIndex++) {
            this.items[tempIndex] = temp.items[tempIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Listable is an interface implemented by the classes Menagerie and Animal, and Menagerie Objects are groups of Animals. Apparently, the problem is that I've allocated the items array but never assigned its elements, so I'm supposed to initialize this.items[tempIndex] as a new Object. However, it could be either an Animal or Menagerie, and I'm not allowed to use instanceOf() to find out which one it is. Also, the Animal Constructor is private, so I can't create a new animal object to begin with.
When I'm trying to add animals to the items array, it adds the first one just fine, but then has a nullpointerexception when I try to add more. I'm sure the solution is something simple and I'm just overthinking this.

Comment: Full stacktrace, please. Save us the effort.

Comment: What's the point of creating a 0-size array?

Comment: @RohitJain - To avoid a NullPointerException!

Comment: Show please also, the code where you call add()

Comment: @TedHopp That isn't a very pretty way of doing that.

Comment: @TedHopp not bad at all, but better would be using an static EMPTY object like Collections.EMPTY

Comment: @VictorZamanian - On the contrary, it is quite pretty. If you can guarantee that a field is never `null`, then you don't need to clutter your code up with `null` tests for that field.

Comment: @AlexWien - It's an array, not a `Collection`.

Comment: @TedHopp An empty array can also be a singleton. No special reason for it to be that, though.

Comment: correct, it is quite pretty. The pattern is called NullObject (or similar) but it is a bit more than he did.

Comment: @TedHopp I guess it depends on one's idea of "*pretty*".

Answer (score 1):

If you call your copy constructor with a `null` argument, then `items` will be `null` and you'll get an NPE in `add`. Either throw an exception from the copy constructor when the arg is null or initialize `items` in all cases.

**EDIT** Your code is very inefficient. I'd suggest using an `ArrayList` for the private `items` field. It does all the work of dynamic sizing for you. Something like this should work:

```
public class SortedListOfImmutables {

    private List<Listable> items;

    /**
     * This constructor creates an empty list.
     */
    public SortedListOfImmutables() {
        items = new ArrayList<Listable>();
    }

    /**
     *  Copy constructor.  The current object will become a copy of the
     *  list that the parameter refers to.  
     *  
     *  The copy must be made in such a way that future changes to
     *  either of these two lists will not affect the other. In other words, 
     *  after this constructor runs, adding or removing things from one of 
     *  the lists must not have any effect on the other list.
     *  
     *  @param other the list that is to be copied
     */
    public SortedListOfImmutables(SortedListOfImmutables other) {
        items = (other == null)
            ? new ArrayList<Listable>()
            : new ArrayList<Listable>(other.items);
    }

    /**
     * Adds an item to the list. This method assumes that the list is already
     * sorted in alphabetical order based on the names of the items
     * in the list.
     * 
     * The new item will be inserted into the list in the appropriate place so
     * that the list will remain alphabetized by names.
     *
     * itemToAdd will not be added if it is null or if it equals an item
     * already in the list.
     *  
     * @param itemToAdd refers to a Listable item to be added to this list
     */
    public void add(Listable itemToAdd) {
        if (itemToAdd != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
                Listable currentItem = items.get(i);
                int comp = itemToAdd.compareTo(currentItem);
                if (comp > 0) continue;
                if (comp < 0) {
                    // do this unconditionally if you want to allow duplicates
                    items.add(i, itemToAdd);
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Apparently, the problem is that I've allocated the items array but
>   never assigned its elements

Yup.  That's definitely a problem that can cause a null pointer exception ;)

> However, it could be either an Animal or Menagerie,

Q: Are both "Animal" and "Menagerie" children of some common parent class?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
public SortedListOfImmutables(SortedListOfImmutables other)
    if(other != null) {
        items = new Listable[other.items.length];

        for(int index=0;index<other.items.length;index++){
            items[index] = other.items[index];
        }
    } else {
       items = new Listable[0];
    }
}
```

otherwise you could create a null list in your new object.